# how do I layer EJB3 and servlets correctly?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, ejb

I am trying to refactor an old application to use EJB3 with JPA.

We have two client layers (one servlet-based, one not) which both call into a delegate layer, which calls an EJB layer, which in turn calls a DAO.  The EJB is EJB2 (bean-managed persistence), and the DAO uses hand-rolled SQL queries, committing transactions and closing connections manually.

I want to replace the EJB2 with EJB3, and change all the DAO to use JPA.

I started off by replacing the EJB2 code with an EJB3 using container-managed transactions.  Since hibernate Criteria are so simple, and the EntityManager can be injected, I can do something like this:

```
@Stateless
public class NewSelfcareBean implements SelfcareTcApi {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="core")
EntityManager em;

public BasicAccount getAccount(String id) {
  Criteria crit = getCriteria(BasicAccount.class);
  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
  BasicAccount acc = (BasicAccount) crit.uniqueResult();
  }
}
```

No need for a separate DAO layer.  The account object looks a bit like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="er_accounts")
public class BasicAccount {
    @OneToMany( mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    protected List<Subscription> subscriptions;
}
```

But in the servlet layer, where I call the EJB to get the account object, I want to build a response which might (or might not) include child subscriptions from the BasicAccount:

The servlet layer looks like this:

```
ResponseBuilder rb;  

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   ...
   Account acc = getDelegateLayer().getAccount();
   rb.buildSubscriptionResponse(acc.getSubscriptions());

   ...
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work since the transaction and entitymanager have been closed by the time we get back to the servlet layer - I get a LazyInitializationException.

So I can see a few options:

1. ServletFilter to manage transactions manually.  This means I lose the benefits of EJB container-managed transactions, doesn't it?  Plus I would have to implement another filter mechanism on the other client (not the end of the world).
2. Use a Stateful session bean instead, then I can use extended persistence context.  But I don't really need a stateful bean, since no data is retained between transactions.  So it would place unnecessary load on the server and I'd be using Stateful for something it wasn't really designed for.
3. Call `Hibernate.init(acc.getSubscriptions())` - this will work but needs to be done in the EJB.  Supposing I re-use the bean for another client method which doesn't need the subscriptions?  An unnecessary DB call.
4. Use EAGER FetchType on my Account object.  Bad for performance and creates unnecessary DB load.

None of these options seems any good.

Am I missing something?  How should this be done?  I can't be the first person to have this problem...

Comment: Query a list of subscriptions associated with an account separately in a separate call to the EJB in question (separate transaction). You may fetch  a subscription list based on an account while in a transaction and have it returned by the EJB method in a separate call.

Comment: Why not make two methods, one for just the BasicAccount, another for BasicAccount with its Subscription prefetched?  Let your application then choose the one it needs

Comment: @Chris, this could work - I could even use just one method, but supply a boolean flag indicating whether I want subscriptions.  But it has a bad code smell.  Is there a JPA equivalent to Hibernate.initialize() ?

Comment: I don't know how Hibernate's initialize() works: it is provider specific and other providers do not disallow loading lazy relationships on detached instances.  I don't know how it would work in your situation, as if you have access to the persistence unit, you can just use JPA queries to fetch the collection, as suggested in Tiny's post.  JPA also added entity graphs as a way to tell what parts of an object model the application is interested in.

Answer (score 6):

Two fetching policies means two use cases, so you are better of writing two methods in this case:

```
public BasicAccount getAccount(String id) {
  Criteria crit = getCriteria(BasicAccount.class);
  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
  BasicAccount acc = (BasicAccount) crit.uniqueResult();
  }
}

public BasicAccount getAccountWithSubscriptions(String id) {
  Criteria crit = getCriteria(BasicAccount.class);
  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
  crit.setFetchMode("subscriptions", FetchMode.JOIN);
  BasicAccount acc = (BasicAccount) crit.uniqueResult();
  }
}
```

[Eager fetching is most often a code smell](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) and it's the service layer (EJB) responsibility to fetch the data. Finding yourself hacking the web layer to add transactional responsibility is a sign of breaking application layer boundaries.

A better approach is to use DTOs. JPA entities are persistence related and they leak the database and the ORM specific fetching retrieval mechanisms. A DTO is a much better fit since it can minimize the amount of data being fetched and sent to the web layer, therefore being ideal for rendering a view. Although you can practically use entities both in the service layer and in the web layer, there are use cases when a data projection is a better alternative.

Comment: Great explanation. Love that you include additional info in the answer to "why".

Comment: The application is 12 years old and a total mess, so I'm reluctant to add yet another layer of code for DTO.  However I do like the idea of using setFetchMode to effectively force EAGER loading on a LAZY join.  We've tested this and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that it ONLY works when you have only one collection.  If you have more than one collection, you get org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Answer (score 1):

This is a VERY typical problem with EAGER/LAZY fetching.

Solution 1 (not the best): Create two methods, one `getBasicAccountWithSubscription()` and one `getBasicAccount()`, like Vlad said. THIS is code smell IMHO. Imagine you have 10 other such relationships. Creating such a method for each possible combination will generate 2^10 (exponential) new methods (like `getBasicAccountWithSubsciptionWithoutLastLoginsWithTelephones...()`), which is not good. Of course you could generate a method with 10 boolean parameters that tell which relationship to fetch, but the method will mix in this case DB stuff (what relationship to load) with business logic parameters (ID of the BasicAccount in your case).

Solution 2 (the best IMHO): create another method in your EJB: `List<Subscription> getSubscriptionsForAccount(Long accountId);` (with the property being fetched lazy). Call the new method where you need the subscriptions of an account. In order to make sure that no one calls your `BasicAccount.getSubscriptions()` method, you could make it private. If you would have 10 relationships you would create a new method for every relationship (thus liniar number of new methods). E.g if you would have another relationship `private List<Login> logins;` in your `BasicAccount` entity, you would add another method to the EJB service `public List<Login> getLoginsForAccount(Long accountId)`.

Comment: Hi, I'm not clear on how solution 2 is supposed to work.  Also, one workaround for the problem with solution 1 is to pass a Map or List of Booleans / Strings, representing the joins required - eg "subscriptions":true, "transactions":false.  So then we only generate one extra method for any number of relationships.

Comment: Your workaround to the problem is still not OK because of the same problem: you mix parameters that represent business logic (parameter `Long accountId`) with parameters that say how to fetch things from DB, which is a bad design.
I edited my answer with some more details. Does it help now? Are you making a Rest Interface or do you use the subscriptions in a JSP?

Comment: yes that's clearer now. To me the workaround simply lists the fields you want to be populated, much like a fetch plan does.  Option 2 would result in more DB calls, if I need to get first the account, then the subscriptions, then the logins, etc. Quicker to do them all with joins in one call.

Comment: Note that in Solution 1, part 2 (with an additional Map as parameter), that is actually another solution, but with the same disadvantage as Solution 1, part 1. Solution2 will NOT generate additional SQL queries. But it will generate additional calls to the EJB, which pretty sure won't be a performance problem.